# NERDTree huge startup time when big file in current directory

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I am using **NERDTree** to navigate through files in Vim. I have a SQLite DB file in the root directory (from where I usually open Vim) which is about 1GB. That file highly affects NERDTree startup time (or the `:NERDTreeToggle` command): about +30sec to open the window. I have tried to include the file in the `NERDTreeIgnore` list but this way the file is just not showing anymore in the sidebar inside Vim (but the startup time is the same). If I open Vim from an inner directory (that does not contain the DB file) it opens in less than 100ms. Is there any way to make NERDTree completely such king of files?

Thanks!

Comment: NERDTree's issue tracker is [over there](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues).

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea to open large files with Vim, as it is well-known for not working as expected with files larger than a couple of megabytes. There are ways to mitigate this to some extent but as Vim is trying to load the full file into memory and buffer refresh times degrade rapidly with large files, there is very little you (or any plugin developer) can do about it. This is caused by the way Vim is written, not a plugin or setting.